# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript On Button Click (within updatepanel) Does not fire on FIRST click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

My project is essentially a web page with a menu and an updatepanel.  The user selects a choice from the menu, and a usercontrol is loaded into the updatepanel.  I would prefer not to use an update panel, but, there are multiple databound controls that contain information that will then change the contents of another databound control.  Anyways, my project calls for a message box to appear on the screen, which I have no issue in getting to work:

```
string s= "<script>alert('HayGuise');</script>";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(c.Page, c.Page.GetType(), GUID.NewGUID().ToString(),s,false);
```

Now, I've tried a number of different tactics, including replacing GUID with a static string; I've used RegisterStartupScript, etc.  My issue is that the message box does not show on the first click of the call button AFTER the updatepanel has updated to show a new usercontrol.  But, if I click the button again, everything is great.  If this is done on the very first form loaded into the updatepanel (opening up the site and selecting from the menu), everything works fine; it is only when the updatepanel updates again with a new form, that this will occur, and again, only on the first click.

Additionally, the code is being fired, and all code that follows the ScriptManager code fires, but the message box will not show until the button is clicked again.  As I am testing this behavior at the moment, I've added the popup code to each of the buttons on the form, and the behavior is the same with each of them. It sucks that its taken so long to implement a reliable piece of code (for the messagebox) only to have this slight issue, and this is after I just figured out why my button events were firing twice on a single click. I pretty sure that it's going to be something simple, some sort of property that I'm not familiar with that needs to be set correctly. Damn, I'd love to just be able to settle all these little issues so I can proceed with the rest of the project.  Sooooo close. Thank you for any help.

Edit: Additionally, the buttons are located in another usercontrol that is added to the usercontrol form that is shown in the updatepanel.

Edit II:
Thanks for your input, I apologize for getting back to this so late, I moved on to other parts of the project and just came back to this.  The issue is not the startupscript method, nor the clientscriptblck method; the issue resides in the loss of value/viewstate/clientid's on postback.

At the time I posted this question, this project was a single page application. I tested functionality by creating a multipage application, and just kept going from there, vowing to come back to this issue.  Well, I'm back and the issue does not reside in the update panel, it has something to do with my code, as I clear out the update panel (tried with a regular panel as well) and then reload the new usercontrol.  When cleared, something goes haywire, and nothing fires on the first postback.  Its a weird issue, that I have yet to find much (a couple articles) information on that is specific to just the first postback causing this issue. I'll update with an answer if I ever find one; the only fix I've found is to add a line to the menu select code, Server.Transfer(thecurrentpage), essentially refreshing the page.  This solves all of the issues, but it seems a bit in poor taste.  Thanks again for your input.

Comment: All browsers have the same issue? Exactly, when you call ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(..) ?

Comment: Tested on IE8 and Firefox, same issue.  Its called on a button click, its in DisplayMessage(Control c, string message) and its only the two lines of code above (instead of 'HayGuise' it would be " + message + ")..

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on first bracet of this method, it's firing at first time? Otherwise, I think your problem is elsewhere on the page, the code you entered is correct (I use it too). In any case, may post a bit more code?
For example: the full method, the opening tag of the update panel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with AJAX UpdatePanel, following code should work for you. In my case, I was using update panel and none of the about worked except this one.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(myUpdatePanelID, myUpdatePanelID.GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using update panel in your page then the following code should work for you. You should use the RegisterStartupScript in the whole page using **"this"**.`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction();", true);`